# int object is not iterable when using dictionary

Tags: python

I know this is a simple error but been looking at it all day! Where do I add float or int to prevent the following error message? int object is not utterable.

How would I print it from highest to lowest score. Can I add reverse=True? I'm getting a tuple error. –

```
scores = {} #You'll need to use a dictionary to store your scores;

with open("classscores1.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        name, score = line.split() #store the name and score separately (with scores converted to an integer)
        score = int(score)
        if name not in scores or scores[name] < score:
            scores[name] = score # replacing the score only if it is higher:

    for name in sorted(scores):
        print(name, "best score is", scores[name])
        print("{}'s best score is {}".format(name, max(scores[name])))
```

Comment: `int` objects aren't iterable *anywhere*.

Comment: `max(scores[name])` Here, `scores[name]` is just a single score, an `int`. Should this be a list of scores for that name instead?

Comment: The last line, which is presumably the one raising the error, looks like it is supposed to do *exactly the same thing* as the line before. So you should probably just delete that problematic line.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
print("{}'s best score is {}".format(name, max(scores[name])))
```

here, you are trying to take the `max` of `scores[name]`, which is just a single integer. Looking at the code, it seems like you already took care of that value being the maximum value, so you can just change that line to

```
print("{}'s best score is {}".format(name, scores[name]))
```

as in the `print` statement above. (Also, since those two `print` lines will print the same thing, you can probably remove one of those two.)

---

To print it from highest to lowest score, change your `for` loop to something like this:

```
for name in sorted(scores, key=scores.get, reverse=True):
    ...
```

This sorts the names in `scores` using the `scores.get` function as key, i.e. it sorts by the values in the dictionary, and the `reverse=True` makes it sort from highest to lowest.

Comment: How would I print it from highest to lowest score. Can I add reverse=True? I'm getting a tuple error.